# Alternative to using usbcopy to create Solaris Text Installer USB stick

Tags: usb, installation, freebsd, dd, solaris

I have a blank T5120 server without any optical drive onto which I want to install Solaris 11.3. I downloaded the `sol-11_3-text-sparc.usb` installer. [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/sliminstall1.html) tell me to use a tool named `usbcopy` to fill a stick.

I don't have this tool since I don't have a Solaris box yet. But I do have FreeBSD running, which reports

```
$ file sol-11_3-text-sparc.usb
sol-11_3-text-sparc.usb: Unix Fast File system [v1] (big-endian),
last mounted on /export/dc/s11/s11_3sru01/builds/text/build_data/tmp/tmpcScvPf-,
last written at Tue Oct  6 16:15:52 2015, clean flag 1,
number of blocks 1014784, number of data blocks 953823,
number of cylinder groups 26, block size 8192, fragment size 1024,
minimum percentage of free blocks 6, rotational delay 0ms,
disk rotational speed 3rps, TIME optimization
```

Can I simply

```
dd if=sol-11_3-text-sparc.usb of=/dev/da3   # Where da3 would be the whole stick
```

or does `usbcopy` provide some extra processing?

Comment: usb copy may format USB drive to hold 2 partition. however your approch looks good. usb tools are also available on windows for what matter. if you feel adventurous, you can run `dd if=sol.iso of=/dev/sda` on server you are running. (at least this work for tumbleweed). **this will reset your system**

Comment: Hopefully needless, but when using dd 1) MAKE SURE YOU SPECIFY THE RIGHT DISK 2) Take care the the pen drive is not mounted. 3) Sync information afterwards (dd has an option for that. IIRc then the console command `sync` no longer guarantees that data is writting to disk so do not use that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usbcopy used to be required, but since 11.2 you can just use dd as you've described.  The only thing usbcopy adds is verifying the copy as it goes.