# Solaris T5120 Unable to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, solaris

### Boot Media Creation

I created a USB boot media on my OS X El Capitan using the following command

[dd if=sol-11_3-text-sparc.usb of=/dev/disk3](https://superuser.com/questions/1017249/alternative-to-using-usbcopy-to-create-solaris-text-installer-usb-stick)

then i waited and made sure it finished successfully without any interruptions

### On my Solaris Box

probe-scsi-all shows, i am assuming this entry "/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/storage@1" is my usb drive

[image: probe-scsi-all]

Then i created an alias
[image: alias creation]

### Now i am trying to boot from my USB and it's failing

[image: booting from usb]

Comment: i just figured it out, i was using the wrong device it needs to be /pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/storage@1/disk basically i went through the list of all usb devices and this one worked. I'll do more testing and post a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Use show-devs

This listed all the devices and following are subset of them

/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,1
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4
**/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/storage@1** -- This was the one from probe-scsi-all

/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4/hid@1
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4/storage@0
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4/storage@0/disk
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/storage@1/disk and -- here's the match one with /disk under it

boot from the last one fixed my issue

Then i create an new alias
nvalias usb /pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/storage@1/disk

To install use

boot usb - install